# Horrible noise coming from speaker when using SDIO

Tags: amplifier, stm32, dac, i2s

I have both an SD card and a [MAX98357A](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max98357a-max98357b.pdf) (I2S Amplifier) breakout board connected to my STM32 Nucleo. As soon as I open a file for reading in FatFs using the `f_open` command, the speaker attached to the MAX98357A starts making a horribly loud pitch static noise and visibly vibrates.

I'm pretty confident that this is due to the 16 MHz clock line that I have running to the SDIO. If I remove any of the SDIO/FatFs functions, then I no longer get that noise, just some occasional clicks. This is all without even initializing any of the I2S peripherals. The breakout board is just connected to power and ground.

Unfortunately, I'm still stuck with breadboarding this for now. Are they any strategies that I could use to remove that noise?

Things I've tried:

- 680 μF and 470 nF capacitor on power and ground rails
- Connecting the MAX98357A to a separate ground PIN
- Using a 5 V regulator for the MAX98357A

Putting my hand on my laptop near the USB port seems to also alleviate the buzzing noise.

Photo for reference:

[image]

Comment: The SD card works with 16MHz clock and these wires? No data errors?

Comment: Yep. I can open a file and read it just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't trust it, these wires are asking for trouble... anyway, you can try putting the decoupling capacitor as close as possible to the class D module. Also investigate if noise couples into the shutdown pin of the amp, which would turn it on/off quickly and make some sounds. Maybe you can put a pullup/pulldown on that pin, see if that fixes it.

Comment: You said that this happens _without_ setting up I2S... what happens if you _do_ setup I2S? ... and what happens if you _don't_ setup I2S, but set the relevant STM32 pins to output and an idle state?

Comment: Still happens in either situation. I noticed though, that it's only the LRC, BLCK, and DATA Pins which causes the noise.

Leaving those pins unplugged and just the power and ground connected, no noise. As soon as I connect one of those pins, noise starts. But the noise starts the moment that my SDIO clock turns on in the code. Before I get to that point in the debugger, everything is quiet.

Comment: honestly, with this setup, you should not expect better than proof of concept performance. If you want to prototype a design where you try to get clean(ish) audio, you at least should go to a soldered setup such as stripboard, or straight to PCB. But you can expect combining a class D amp with lots of digital activity to be a struggle, because class D relies on keeping switching noise out of the audio band. The moment you introduce even very low level HF noise at other frequencies it tends to modulate down into audible interference and it is usually very noticeable.

Comment: If you run 16MHz through these long cables and that breadboard, you have created a pretty good EMI generator. With the side affect of being able to read SD cards, apparently. Breadboards in general are only good for one single thing: creating problems.

Comment: _Are they any strategies that I could use to remove that noise?_ Yes. Carefully place the breadboard into a garbage bin, and take it as a lesson. As a bare minimum, you can try to use separate ground and power for the two devices; but you should also use signal returns (grounds) separate from power supply ground.

Comment: Have you connected a scope to those lines and "see" what's going on?

Comment: Figured it out, it ended up being my GPIO slew rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. My GPIO Slew rate was too high. It was introducing too much EMI. Lowering it fixed the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer (I think the site will allow you within two days) so the question does not remain open.